# Modal-Backdrop Gone When Modal Loads Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I want to load the content in modal with function below:

```
<body>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
 function loadModalContent(e, url){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#listmodal').load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
        var el_modal = $(this);
        if (status == "success") {
            el_modal.modal({ show: true });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

when the modal loads the content, I click a button in the modal then load another content in the same modal. however, this causes the modal-backdrop disappear. I can't click any other space to quit the modal. Any solution and why modal-backdrop would disappear?

Comment: I feel you should be loading your content in `.modal-body` div and hence your code should be `$('#listmodal .modal-body')`.. However, it will be good if post the complete code with `html` and also click event inside `modal`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao hi. I did load the content in modal-body. check out my edits.

Comment: Yea.. What content is loaded in `modal`.. Post the rendered `html`.. Also post the `click event`...